# DAL Returns a collection of business objects in MVP

Tags: c#, object-oriented, .net, mvp, ado.net

In Model View Presenter (`MVP`) pattern, it is said that our `DAL` always should returns business models.

1. If I want to get a list of business objects from my `DAL`, is it acceptable to do it as follows or better to get a `DataTable` from `DAL` and then in the applications `BLL`, converts it to a `List`?

   ```
   public List<Employee>  GetNewEmployees()
   {
       string selectStatement = "SELECT Employee.Emp_ID, Employee.Initials + ' ' + Employee.Surname AS Name,...";

       using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(db.GetConnectionString))
       {
           using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, sqlConnection))
           {
               sqlConnection.Open();
               using (SqlDataReader dataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
               {
                   List<Employee> list = new List<Employee>();
                   while (dataReader.Read())
                   {
                       list.Add (
                       new EpfEtfMaster { 
                           EmployeeID = (int) dataReader ["emp_id"],
                           EmployeeName = (string) dataReader ["Name"],
                           AppointmentDate = (DateTime) dataReader["appointment_date"],                                   
                       });                            
                   }
                   return list;
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Your Question

`System.Data.DataTable` lives under the `System.Data` namespace; one good way to start mixing concerns in your BLL is to reference `System.Data`, and then you don't even need a DAL any more and can have your BLL directly access the database. Or worse, have *some* of your data access code code in the DAL, and then *some more* data access code in the BLL.

Doesn't sound like a good idea? Then leave `DataTable` where it belongs: hidden/encapsulated as an *implementation detail* of your DAL.

You're using ADO.NET *now*, but if you decide to reimplement your DAL with Entity Framework or Linq-to-SQL, that decision shouldn't require modifying your BLL in any way, because the BLL shouldn't know anything that has anything to do with data access.

If the BLL needs *employees*, return *employees*, not some `DataTable`.

---

#### Your Code

> ```
> public List<Employee>  GetNewEmployees()
> ```

You should return an `IEnumerable<Employee>`, not a `List<Employee>`; `List<T>` will be confusing for the BLL to receive, because it has `Add` and `AddRange` members which allow client code to *add items to the list*, making the returned value *something else* than just a list of "new employees" taken from the DAL.

> ```
> {
>     string selectStatement = "SELECT Employee.Emp_ID, Employee.Initials + ' ' + Employee.Surname AS Name,...";
>
>     using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(db.GetConnectionString))
>     {
>         using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, sqlConnection))
>         {
>             sqlConnection.Open();
>             using (SqlDataReader dataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
>             {
> ```

A `using` block opens a *scope*, and in C# we denote scopes with braces `{ }` - it is *almost always* a good idea to be explicit about scopes, both for readability and for maintainability.

However in the case of `using` blocks, it's often more readable to reduce nesting and to *stack* these blocks where possible, using braces `{ }` only where they are needed:

```
 using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(db.GetConnectionString))
 using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, sqlConnection))
 {
     sqlConnection.Open();
     using (SqlDataReader dataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
     {
```

The reason why this works, is because when braces are not specified, a scope spans only a single instruction (like, `if (1 == 1) DoSomething();` and `if (1 == 1) { DoSomething(); }` are equivalent). However if that *single instruction* opens a new scope, that scope gets encompassed in the "parent" one, which allows you to "stack" these `using` blocks and reduce nesting.

> ```
>                 List<Employee> list = new List<Employee>();
>                 while (dataReader.Read())
>                 {
>                     list.Add (
>                     new EpfEtfMaster { 
>                         EmployeeID = (int) dataReader ["emp_id"],
>                         EmployeeName = (string) dataReader ["Name"],
>                         AppointmentDate = (DateTime) dataReader["appointment_date"],                                   
>                     });                            
>                 }
>                 return list;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

There are no changes to make in that part, to return an `IEnumerable<Employee>`, because `List<Employee>` implements the `IEnumerable<Employee>` interface, so your method can work with a `List<T>` and only return an `IEnumerable<T>` to its clients, keeping the ability to add/remove items all for itself :)

It's just **very unclear and surprising** why you're adding a `new EpfEtfMaster` instead of an `Employee`. The name `EpfEtfMaster` should be renamed to something much more explicit, and again I don't see the reason why a `List<Employee>` would want to take `EpfEtfMaster` items.

I would also rename `list` to either `employees` or `result` - `list` is just too vague.

Answer (score 6):

You don't want to pull the entire Employee table unless necessary.

```
public IEnumerable<Employee>  GetNewEmployees()
{
    string selectStatement = "SELECT Employee.Emp_ID, Employee.Initials + ' ' + Employee.Surname AS Name,...";

    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(db.GetConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, sqlConnection))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader dataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    yield return new EpfEtfMaster(){ 
                        EmployeeID = (int) dataReader ["emp_id"],
                        EmployeeName = (string) dataReader ["Name"],
                        AppointmentDate = (DateTime) dataReader["appointment_date"],                                   
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By switching to `IEnumerable` and `yield return`, when you call `GetNewEmployees().First()`, only the first row is read.

---

- The names like `sqlCommand`, `sqlConnection` and `dataReader` can be shortened to `command`, `connection` and `reader` without affecting the reader.
- Try to not repeat yourself with `SomeThing someThing = new SomeThing(...);`. The first class name can be replaced by using `var`.

Result :

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(db.GetConnectionString))
```

---

```
new SqlConnection(db.GetConnectionString)
```

Use verb for method and noun for field/properties. Here `GetX` suggest it is a method but is used like a property, you can rename it to `ConnectionString`.